# Is there way to allow access in Nginx configuration to a script, only if the browser accessed the server previously?

Tags: nginx, cgi

My websites are static. I am looking for a method to protect the CGI form, without using "Captcha". Further, I do not wish to relay on referer because that may be vague and incorrect.

Is there any method that I can allow the access to CGI only and provided that browser already accessed a page on the same server?

That implies that Nginx should hopefully be able to keep track if the client was already on the page.

Comment: `nginx` doesn't support `CGI`.

Comment: I use it as proxy, so it works